# how to call onPropertyChanged for property in another class wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have listbox in datagrid created as a datatemplate, and that listbox contains checkbox inside.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Skills" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Skills, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SaveChangesCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In viewmodel class I have Employees collection which contains Skills property(listbox above is bindend on Skills). Also in viewmodel I have NumberOfSkills property beacuse I want when all checkbox inside listbox are checked that datagrid row starts blinking.

```
private ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> _employees;
    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set
        {
            _employees = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }

public int NumberOfSkills 
    {
        get 
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach(SkillViewModel skill in ((EmployeeViewModel)SelectedRow).Skills)
            {
                if(skill.IsChecked)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Skills is property in EmployeeViewModel class.

```
public ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel> Skills
    {
        get 
        {
            ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel> skills = new ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel>();

            if (employee.Skills != null)
            {
                foreach (Skill skill in employee.Skills)
                {
                    skills.Add(new SkillViewModel { Name = skill.Name, IsChecked = skill.IsChecked });
                }
            }
            if (skills.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (SkillsEnum skill in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SkillsEnum)))
                {
                    skills.Add(new SkillViewModel { Name = skill.ToString(), IsChecked = false });
                }
            }
            return skills;
        }
        set 
        {
            List<Skill> list = new List<Skill>();
            foreach (SkillViewModel skill in (ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel>)value)
            {
                list.Add(new Skill { Name = skill.Name, IsChecked = skill.IsChecked });
            }
            employee.Skills = list; 
        }
    }
```

SkillViewModel look like:

```
public class SkillViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _isChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NumberOfSkills");
            OnPropertyChanged("Skills");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

Skill class is serializable so that class can't implement BaseViewModel(INotifyPropertyChanged).

Ok now...When I checked or unchecked checkbox in view, that property is changed in SkillViewModel. But how can I notify that is NumberOfSkills is also changed, because datagrid row can't start blinking without this. DataTrigger looks:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NumberOfSkills}" Value="3">
```

I am new in WPF, a really try to do this. I also know that code is note the best,and you can help me at any way.